# Can a github collaborator commit their changes to a public repo?

Tags: github

I was added as collaborator to a public GitHub repo and I was able to make changes to the main branch. A pull request was not generated, the changes just went right in. I am using Visual Studio 2015 as my client, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it **depends on the permission**.

There are 4 types of permissions:

1. Read
2. Write
3. Admin
4. Owner

Note: Organization members with owner permissions have extensive permissions across all repositories in an organization.

See the permissions and associated actions at [Repository permission levels for an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/) and  [Collaborator access on a repository owned by a user account](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/).

Comment: OK: Read-only is a GitHub user who is not owner, admin, or collaborator. Read/Write is a GitHub user who is a collaborator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is either your responsibility to properly follow process (i.e., create a branch and then create the pull request to merge to master / release / etc) or/and up to the repo owner to set up permissions so committing directly to master is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's basically what collaborators are. :)

See [Github - Collaborator access on a repository owned by a user account](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account)

Often, even if you have collaborator access/rights, you can choose to adopt a more kosher Git workflow, like creating a branch and a pull request for each 'thing' that goes into the main branch.